# Seemingly unrelated error when declaring variable type

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I'm setting up a very basic typescript project and getting a seemingly unrelated error when declaring the type of a variable. I'm trying to express that a variable can be either a string, or null, or undefined [**Edit**] I'm aware that this is the default for string, I'm trying to express this when using typescript 2.0's non-nullable types. Here is a screenshot of the squiggly lines and error:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mBw9.png)

Code (offending code denoted by "^^^^"s):

```
var testMessage: string | null | undefined;
                          ^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^
class TestClass {
testMessage: string | null | undefined;
                      ^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^
    constructor() {
    }
}
```

Error Message:
"Type Expected. The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type."

The error is the same both for the lone variable and the one inside the class, and the only difference in the error is that it says 'right-hand side' for the undefined entries.

I'm using VSCode 1.4.0. 
My folder structure is a 'src' and a 'dist' folder sitting side by side in an enclosing project root folder where my tsconfig.json and npm package file reside. 
I have tsc watching the 'src' folder and recompiling on save.
I used 'npm install -g typescript@next' but the same occurs with 'typescript@beta' and 'typescript@2.0'.
The error occurs irrespective of setting my workspace settings to grab tsdk from its global installation directory or not.
My tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "watch": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true
    }
}
```

Declaring variable types this way was working fine on another project yesterday, but now that project too has this error. Does anyone know what is causing this and how I can fix it?

[**Edit** : Context for my confusion]
This throws no errors on another machine under typescript 2.1 / typescript@next:

```
export class SomeClass {
    constructor(public someParameter:     string | undefined,
                public someOtherParamter: string | undefined = undefined ) {
        //Some constructor code here
    }

    someFoo (someParam: SomeClass | SomeExtendedClass) : SomeOtherClass 
    {
    //some code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Please paste your error here. So anyone can search it. Also in someday your error image link maybe broken.

Comment: @ykaragol added some otehr calrifications too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question because the only other answer is unrelated to the cause of my issue.

The syntax in my question is valid and correct under typescript version 2.1.0-dev.20160810 (what you get at the time of writing from typescript@next). The problem came from me expecting

'npm link **typescript**'

to link the new version of typescript I'd just installed  with 'npm install typescript@next'. Instead it linked the default installed typescript version (1.8 in my case). It was fixed by entering

'npm link **typescript@next**'.

I hit upon the solution when trying to reinstall typescript@next from npm and it complaining about being unable to update due to symlinks.

Answer (score 0):

In typescript you don't declare your variables like that. You can say something like this.

```
 var name : String;
```

This can be null or undefined as well, it is quite well understood that when you have a variable, it might not be used yet and hence not hold a value (so it can be either null or undefined). Hence the reason that in other languages you can get all those `NullpointerExceptions`.

### Meaning behind the error

What the error is telling you, is that you are trying to use an artihmetic operation at that point. Because what you are trying to do is not supported in the Typescript syntax, thus it tries to resolve what you are doing as an arithmetic expression. You are trying to assign the result of the expression `string | null | undefined` to the variable `testMessage`. This 'equation' is nonsensical to typescript. What you have written is a `bitwise OR operation`.

Comment: I'm using the typescript 2.0's beta feature 'non-nullable types' mentioned here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/07/11/announcing-typescript-2-0-beta/. I'm under the impression the syntax is supported in this version of typescript. Am I wrong? See my edit above for why I'm confused.